# What did I do wrong in installing ubuntu 20? Dual boot failed and everything pointed to "Make sure you are using the right arch type"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue

So I installed Ubuntu 20 64 bit version, after 2 days I booted my laptop and it went to Grub Rescue. I found the `normal.mod` to be in `/usr/lib/grub/i368` ( cant remember exact path) but definitely not where it was supposed to be (/boot/) . And, in the boot folder I could see that the file names that were been shown were gibberish.

I did the `insmod normal` and then typed out `normal`, it took me to grub. I could not understand what to do next, people suggested insmod linux and then linux commands but those files were not present.

Then, I used Kali live on a USB and tried a rescue by mounting. I could not mount `/dev`. I had to perform some cleanups and then I was able to mount. After that, I needed to use `chroot`. It gave the error of `/bin/bash Exec format`. Now a solution to this was I am using the wrong bit version but my processor is 64 bit, I use a 64 bit Windows.

I deleted the partition and used Windows installation for as a boot rescue.

I really need to install Ubuntu again, but now I am scared this will lead to something more messy. What did I do wrong, why did this grub mess up?